# Postgresql union query with priority on one query

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a table with 2 columns

```
class_id | title          
CS124    | computer tactics          
CS101    | intro to computers          
MATH157  | math stuff          
CS234    | other CS stuff          
FRENCH50 | TATICS of french          
ENGR101  | engineering ETHICS      
OTHER1   | other CS title
```

I want to do a sort of smart search for auto complete where a user searches for something.

Lets say they type 'CS' into the box I want to search using both the `class_id` and `title` with a limit of lets say 5 for this example. I first want to search for class_ids like 'CS%' with a limit of 5 ordered by class_id. This will return the 3 cs classes.

Then if there is any room left in the limit I want to search using title like '%CS% and combine them but have the `class_id` matches be first, and make sure that duplicates are removed from the bottom like like cs234 where it would match on both queries.

So the end result for this query would be

```
CS101    | intro to computers          
CS124    | computer tactics          
CS234    | other CS stuff          
ENGR101  | engineering ETHICS          
FRENCH50 | TATICS of french
```

I am trying to do something like this

```
(select * from class_infos
 where LOWER(class_id) like LOWER('CS%')
 order by class_id)

union

(select * from class_infos
 where LOWER(title) like LOWER('%CS%')
 order by class_id)

limit 30
```

But it is not putting them in the right order or make the `class id` query have priority. Anyone have any suggestions

Here is the sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b

Comment: Hello Tomer, next time try to provide a [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34cfe/2) so we can help you faster and better

Comment: What I would try is to assign your own priority value to both sub-queries, and them do a select from results by order with a specified limit. Perhaps there are better solutions, but this is something that comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try something like this?

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/55164/1)

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    (select 1 as priority, * 
     from class_infos
     where LOWER(class_id) like LOWER('CS%'))
  union
    (select 2 as priority, * 
     from class_infos
     where 
             LOWER(title) like LOWER('%CS%')
     and not LOWER(class_id) like LOWER('CS%') 
    )
  ) as class
ORDER BY priority, class_id
limit 5
```